# Javascript: how to send multiple data in Ajax or Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im sorry but im confused if its really AJAX or JSON, i am not good at this language.
but my problem is sending 2 listbox value. the year and the month. the year is sending to the `data-basic-colm-ajax.php` but i don't know how to send the month

here's my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //default

            getAjaxData(new Date().getFullYear());

            $('.dynamic_data').change(function() {
                var id = $('#year').val();
                var id2 = $('#month').val();
                getAjaxData(id);
            });

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts Chart PHP with MySQL Example',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Subtitle',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'TOTAL'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>:<b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y}'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -40,
                    y: 100,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: true
                },
                series: []
            };
            function getAjaxData(id) {
                $.getJSON("data-basic-colm-ajax.php", {id:id}, function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //xAxis: {categories: []}
                    options.series[0] = json[1];                        
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            }

        });
    </script>

    <script src="/MyCharts/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <a class="link_header" href="/highcharts/">&lt;&lt; Back to index</a>
    <div class="menu_top" >
        Year:
        <select class="dynamic_data" id="year">
            <option value="2016" >2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
        </select>
        Month:
        <select id="month">
            <option value="1" selected>Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</body>
```

Thank You

Comment: `AJAX` is the approach of making an asynchronous request to your server while `JSON` is the notation you write your objects so that your client and server could communicate and pass data to and from each other. Both work hand in hand.

Comment: Id2 is declared but never used. You are only passing Id into the getAjaxData function

Comment: @Magrangs though i did try `$.getJSON("data-basic-colm-ajax.php", {id:id , id2:id2}, function(json)` . is that what u mean? or this `getAjaxData(id,id2); ` ?

Comment: Nevermind guys I have fixed it =)

Answer (score 0):

i just change my codes to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/MyCharts/highcharts/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //default

            getAjaxData(new Date().getFullYear());

            $('.dynamic_data').change(function() {
                var id = $('#year').val();
                var id2 = $('#month').val();
                var data = {id:id ,id2:id2};
                getAjaxData(data);
            });

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Highcharts Chart PHP with MySQL Example',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Subtitle',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'TOTAL'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>:<b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y}'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -40,
                    y: 100,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: true
                },
                series: []
            };
            function getAjaxData(data) {
                var year = $('#year').val();
                var month = $('#month').val();
                $.getJSON("data-basic-colm-ajax.php",{id:year ,id2:month}, function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; //xAxis: {categories: []}
                    options.series[0] = json[1];                        
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            }

        });
    </script>

    <script src="/MyCharts/highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <a class="link_header" href="/highcharts/">&lt;&lt; Back to index</a>
    <div class="menu_top" >
        Year:
        <select class="dynamic_data" id="year">
            <option value="2016" >2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
        </select>
        Month:
        <select id="month">
            <option value="1" selected>Jan</option>
            <option value="2">Feb</option>
            <option value="3">Mar</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are passing in a variable called 'data' to getAjaxData but you are not actually using it. You might as well get rid of it.